# How can I JOIN static values and use them as GROUP BY identifier?

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have created a `SELECT` statement where I fetch the time difference from now to a certain date in my database.

```
SELECT
    `username`,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, `a_date`, NOW()) AS `timediff`
FROM
    `User`
```

... results in something like

```
username | timediff
-------------------
john     |      441
henry    |     1624
mike     |        4
kyle     |     NULL
```

Now I would like to group them into pre defined groups, e.g.

- `NULL`
- `less than 20`
- `greater than 20`

How can I `JOIN` the above result with a static set of predefined values and how can I use those values as my grouping identifier?

```
group | amount
--------------
NULL  |      1
lt 20 |      1
gt 20 |      2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `case` statement with `group by`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, `a_date`, NOW()) < 20 THEN 'lt 20'
             WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, `a_date`, NOW()) >= 20 THEN 'gt 20'
        END) as grp, COUNT(*)
FROM `User`
GROUP BY grp;
```

As a side note:  I usually repeat the `case` statement in the `group by`, because many databases don't allow column aliases there:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, `a_date`, NOW()) < 20 THEN 'lt 20'
             WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, `a_date`, NOW()) >= 20 THEN 'gt 20'
        END) as grp, COUNT(*)
FROM `User`
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, `a_date`, NOW()) < 20 THEN 'lt 20'
               WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, `a_date`, NOW()) >= 20 THEN 'gt 20'
          END);
```

Comment: Uhh, great answer! I thought of a `LEFT JOIN` and defining static intervals. This is really slack, thanks a lot!